# Plot a list of pairs

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

How shall I plot this list of `zm` vs. `zs`?

Should I extract the individual list first?

```
phase = {{zm -> 12.735357153161043513, zs -> 9.7234898615983598324}, {zm -> 12.439795620502032594, zs -> 9.5677333839734501010}, {zm -> 12.322794261025035959, zs -> 9.5083406581264741392}, {zm -> 12.283443749378536461, zs -> 9.4885610867682085673}, {zm -> 12.270768716468870474, zs -> 9.4822083318853045563}, {zm -> 12.266737552360516880, zs -> 9.4801896991994617103}, {zm -> 12.265460495293092574, zs -> 9.4795503825168381655}, {zm -> 12.265056425467359123, zs -> 9.4793481160147239450}, {zm -> 12.264928624482637468, zs -> 9.4792841440516469762}, {zm -> 12.264888207974288607, zs -> 9.4792639133728615843}}
```

Comment: `ListPlot[Values /@ phase]` or `ListPlot[Association /@ phase]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
ListPlot[{zm, zs} /. phase]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
phase//{#[[All,1,2]], #[[All,2,2]]}&//Transpose

(* {
    {12.73535715316104351, 9.723489861598359832}, 
    {12.43979562050203259, 9.567733383973450101}, 
    {12.32279426102503596, 9.508340658126474139}, 
    {12.28344374937853646, 9.488561086768208567}, 
    {12.27076871646887047, 9.482208331885304556}, 
    {12.26673755236051688, 9.480189699199461710}, 
    {12.26546049529309257, 9.479550382516838166}, 
    {12.26505642546735912, 9.479348116014723945}, 
    {12.26492862448263747, 9.479284144051646976}, 
    {12.26488820797428861, 9.479263913372861584}
   } *)

phase//{#[[All,1,2]], #[[All,2,2]]}&//Transpose//ListPlot
```